# Oracle enterprise manager showing wrong port after change

Tags: oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager

I changed the port that Oracle was using from 1523 to the default 1521. The database is running on the correct port now. I can connect on 1521 and run queries.

However the Enterprise Manager is still showing that the port is 1523, and that the database is down.

Why doesn't the OEM know that I'm using the new port? How do I fix this?

Edit: I think I changed the port the wrong way. I changed the listener.ora file, the tnsnames.ora file and ran alter system set LOCAL_LISTENER="(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))";

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Using Oracle 10g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to de-install the enterprise manager and then re-install it using the `emca` command. We'll leave that for the worst case.

### Using EMCA After Changing the Database Listener Port

> If you change the listener port of the database after you have configured Database Control, **the database status will appear as down**. To reconfigure Database Control so it uses the new listener port, run the EMCA command using the `-config dbcontrol db [-cluster]` command-line arguments.

<sup>(**emphasis** mine)</sup>

***Reference:*** [Enterprise Manager Advanced Configuration](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40002/structure.htm) (Oracle Docs 10g)

In your case you would run the following commands:

```
SET ORACLE_HOME= your_oracle_home
SET ORACLE_SID= your_oracle_sid

emca -config dbcontrol db
```

You might have to provide various pieces of information when re-configuring the Enterprise Manager:

- port
- SID
- DBSNMP_PWD
- SYSMAN_PWD
- HOST_USER
- HOST_USER_PWD
- SYS_PWD

If this doesn't reconfigure the database control for your instance you might have to re-create the repository containing all the Entrprise Management Console configuration settings. You would achieve this be adding a parameter to the previous command:

```
SET ORACLE_HOME= your_oracle_home
SET ORACLE_SID= your_oracle_sid

emca -deconfig dbcontrol db
emca -config dbcontrol db -repos recreate
```

This will de-configure the EM Console settings for a database (not for a cluster installation) and then recreate the repository.

The additional information I listed above will be required for a re-configuration to work.

> **DISCLAIMER**
>   Re-configuring the Enterprise Management Console is no easy task. **I have failed many times** (especially with broken timezone settings). If you are unsure or don't feel in the position to risk your installation, please consider contacting an Oracle Consultant.
>
> If you have a test environment, consider trying this out there first.